# how to get content type nodes in drupal 7?

Tags: wordpress, drupal-7

is there a way to get content type node in drupal 7 ?
lets say i have a content type (news) and i  want last 5 or 10 node with their fields and image to show them in a block in front page.
so what is the specific functions to do that
like wordpress :  
[get_posts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts)

and what if the site is multilingual and I'm using i18n module
is there a functions to get last 5 by English and other for other language ?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do that is to use the **[Views](http://drupal.org/project/views)** module

> **You need Views if**
>
> - You like the default front page view, but you find you want to sort it
>     differently.
> - You like the default taxonomy/term view, but you find you want to sort it
>     differently; for example,
>     alphabetically.
> - You use /tracker, but you want to restrict it to posts of a certain
>     type.
> - You like the idea of the 'article' module, but it doesn't display
>     articles the way you like.
> - **You want a way to display a block with the 5 most recent posts of
>     some particular type.**
> - You want to provide 'unread forum posts'.
> - You want a monthly archive similar to the typical Movable Type/Wordpress
>     archives that displays a link to the
>     in the form of "Month, YYYY (X)" where
>     X is the number of posts that month,
>     and displays them in a block. The
>     links lead to a simple list of posts
>     for that month.

Views is also able to handle multilingual issues.

Comment: ok this seems to be good
but i have noticed that the view module display a query for the result i need 
but i think there are additional functions & queries in the front end that shows every thing
for example (the custom image thumbnail which is a field) & a link for node it self , so how cand i display this full rendered queries ?